# Macro statements used in a header file, but defined outside of it

Tags: c, macros, header

I'm writing some libraries for a microcontroller, and I've organized these libraries in sections with respect to their function. For example, I have `adc.h` to configure analog input measurements, `uart.h`, and `i2c.h` for digital communication etc.

Some of these libraries need information on a CPU speed, so I've defined a macro statement

```
#define FCY 30000000UL
```

inside all header files that need this piece of information. My question is, can I program somehow these header files in a way that the `FCY` macro is only "declared" in the header file, but is defined outside of it, e.g. in a `main.c` file? The problem is, when I change the CPU speed (frequency), I have to update all these `FCY` macro statements, which is prone to error.

Comment: You could always put that in a single header that is included by all your other headers, couldn't you? If you can edit the headers and throw in `#define` certainly you can edit them and put in a `#include`. Or just use a /D compiler directive and throw it directly in the defined macros from the command line.

Comment: Macros are not defined and declared.  You can redefine a macro if you want, but apart of being expanded in your code, they have no storage in your program.  All your expanded macro substitutions will be on the executable, but without any information related to their definition or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to provide a separate header file like, for example, `hardware_constants.h` for things that need to be the same across several `.h` files or `c`-files. Include `hardware_constants.h` where needed instead of (re)defining the same thing many times.

You could even let the one invoking the compiler provide these definitions, e.g. at the command line, in your make-file, or in the project settings of your IDE.

And some IDEs provide headers that are automatically included before every translation unit. In XCode projects, for example, you can place common `#define ...`-statements in a file called `PrefixHeader.pch`, and these definitions will be implicitly available in every source code file.

Comment: I hoped there was a more elegant way to deal with this. I'll just use an additional header file that defines everything needed by other libraries. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do not define `FCY` at all in any source-/header-file, but just when invoking the compiler.

For GCC you can do this using the option `-D` like this:

```
gcc src1.c src2.c main.c -o main -DFCY=30000000UL
```

This way the pre-processor "sees" `FCY` the way as `#define`d via option `-D` for all three files: `src1.c`, `src2.c` and `main.c`

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps the solution is to make FCY definition to depend on another macro definition where you have stored the SPEED info, like:

```
#define SPEED 345
```

and in other file

```
#define FCY 30000##SPEED##UL
```

That will substitute/expand `FCY` in your code by `30000345UL`  so you can change individually the `SPEED` macro and the `FCY` macro.

In case some formula is to be applied, you can do something like this:

#define SPEED 345

and in the cpu file:

```
#define FCY  (300000000UL | (SPEED))
```